# How to Execute chrome master preferences?

Tags: google-chrome

I have now made a valid JSON file, I downloaded the Enterprise MSI file.

Know the the question, where do i put the "master_preferences" or how do i execute the msi file to use the file?
I have tried to google it but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187948?hl=en) you should place it next to the chrome executable (chrome.exe), on a Windows system the filepath would be C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\master_preferences

Comment: this dont work =/

Comment: @TorbjörnDahlgren Either you need to restart the computer, or fully restart Chrome. It could also be the JSON (though you said it was valid so I doubt that), [doublecheck anyway](http://jsonlint.com/). It might also be that the master_preferences file is only used when Google Chrome is started for the **first** time, used as a way for businesses to deploy chrome on many computers. If that's the case this is probably not what you want to do. May I ask what you're trying to achieve?